# Python убрать пробел между кавычками и текстом

Tags: python, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Имеется код:

```
import re

class Interpreter:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file_name = filename
        variables = {}
        with open(filename) as code:
            self.lines = len(code.readlines())
        self.current_line = 1

    def split_code(self, input_str):
        pattern = r'\w+|\.|\=|<.*?>|\"w+"'
        result = re.findall(pattern, input_str)
        for i in range(len(result)):
            try:
                result[i] = int(result[i])
            except ValueError:
                pass
        return result

    def lex(self, c):
        n = 0
        x = 0
        c = " ".join(c)
        print(c)

    def run(self):
        with open(self.file_name, "r", encoding="utf-8") as code:
            while self.current_line <= self.lines:
                line = code.readline().replace("\n", "")
                codeline = self.split_code(line)
                self.lex(codeline)
                self.current_line += 1




inter = Interpreter("programm.txt")
inter.run()
```

В строке `pattern = r'\w+|\.|\=|<.*?>|\"w+"'` добавил в самом конце `\"w+"`, не знаю, правильно ли сделал, но не работает. Суть в том, что текст из файла `programm.txt`
Содержащий это:

```
out "Привет мир!"
```

Преобразуется в массив а затем склеивается в текст НЕ УЧИТЫВАЯ кавычки. То есть он их просто игнорит, но мне нужно чтобы при получении массива `['out', '"', 'Привет', 'мир', '"']` в строку должно склеиваться вот так: `out "Привет мир"`, то есть кавычки должны быть прикреплены к тексту.
Кто знает и поможет, буду благодарен.

Comment: Т. е. что-то вроде `pattern = r'\w+(?:\s*"[^"]*")?|<[^<>]*>|[.=]`?

Comment: добавлять если что надо было не `\"w+"` а `"\w+"` (без учета корректности смысловой)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew сделал так, но теперь вывод такой: ['out "Привет мир!"']. То есть все идет в один элемент списка

Comment: @teran не помогло

Comment: А как должно быть? У вас в вопросе написано: *в строку должно склеиваться вот так: `out "Привет мир"`*. ???

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew должно быть вот так:

Comment: Вот КАК????????????